# Login forms show up sometimes, sometimes they don't

Tags: html, css, python-2.7, flask

I'm building a personal site using Flask and SQLAlchemy. I've been having problems getting my /login route to display properly. It worked, then I changed my `.page` class margin in my CSS *from* auto and then back again, and then my login forms stopped displaying entirely.

What I can't figure out is what I did to make them disappear -- I cut my server off a couple of times and restarted it, and the page didn't load. When I came back quite a bit later, I restarted my server *again* and the login page loaded. I thought that it was "solved", but then when I came back a couple of hours later, the login page won't load again. All of my other extended HTML pages load correctly, just not my login page with my login forms.

I don't have a link anchor for the login page -- I just access it by typing out the route (/login).

Here is my relevant code:

**views.py** (auth blueprint)

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, request, url_for, flash
from flask.ext.login import login_user
from . import auth
from ..models import User
from .forms import LoginForm

@auth.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  form = LoginForm()
  """if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data.first())
    if (user is not None) and user.verify_password( form.password.data):
      login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
      return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))
    flash('Invalid username or password.')"""
  return render_template('auth/login.html', title = "Log in", form = form)
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>
  {% block title %}
  perSimmons
  {% endblock %}
</title>

<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li id="banner"><a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">{ perSimmons }</a></li>
      <li id="links"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li id="links"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
      <li id="links"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li id="links"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>

    <div class=page>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}perSimmons - {{title}} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class=page-header>
  <h3>Admin Login</h3>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
  <p id="user-login">
    Username:<br>
    {{form.email}}<br>
    Password:<br>
    {{form.password}}<br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Log in">{{form.remember_me}}Stay signed-in </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceCodeProRegular';
    src: url('fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf.woff');
    src: local('SourceCodePro Regular'), local('SourceCodePro'), url('fonts/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf.woff') format('truetype');
}
body            { font-family: 'SourceCodeProRegular'; background: #CC3300; }
a, h2       { color: #CC3300; }
h1, h2          { font-family: 'SourceCodeProRegular'; margin: 0; }
h1              { border-bottom: 2px solid #CC3300; }
h2              { font-size: 2em; font-weight: bold; }
h3      { color: #CC3300;}
li          { color: #CC3300;}
dl      { color: #CC3300;}
p       { color: #CC3300;}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #CC3300;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #999966;
    border-top: 5px solid #999966;
    border-left: 5px solid #999966;
    border-right: 5px solid #999966;
}

#nav #banner { font-weight:bold; }

#nav li { float:left; }

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFF66;
    border-right: 2px solid #999966;
    }

#nav li a:hover {
    color:#CC3300;
    background-color: #FFFF66;
    }

.page {
    margin: 2em auto;
    width: 55em;
    border: 5px solid #999966;
        padding: 0.8em;
    background: #FFFF66;
    }

.entries {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

.entries li     { margin: 0.8em 1.2em; }

.entries li h2  { margin-left: -1em;}

.add-entry {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CC3300;
    }

.flash {
    font-color: #999966;
    font-family: 'SourceCodeProRegular';
    background: #CC3300;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #aacbe2;
    }

.error {
    background: #f0d6d6;
    padding: 0.5em;
    }
```

Comment: If you view the source of the page in the web-browser, do you see the code for the form?

Comment: I do not see the code for the forms.

Comment: What do you see?  Do you see the <form> tag, do you see the <h3>Admin Login</h3> Code?  I'm trying to find out what about the template isn't being shown.

Comment: It shows my `layout.html` file, but instead of displaying my `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` between my `<div class=page>` tags, it shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure you're working on the `/templates/auth/login.html` code-- try creating a new template called `/templates/abcd.html` and seeing rendering that view with your code works.

Comment: I see what went wrong. I was trying to access my login route with `/login`; the correct route was `auth/login`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct route for `login.html` in the auth blueprint is `/auth/login` -- not `/login`. Everything loaded correctly when I made this change.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `form.csrf_token`.

My forms disappeared sporatically without this present. Try the following:

**login.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}perSimmons - {{title}} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class=page-header>
  <h3>Admin Login</h3>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
  {{form.csrf_token}}
  <p id="user-login">
    Username:<br>
    {{form.email}}<br>
    Password:<br>
    {{form.password}}<br>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Log in">{{form.remember_me}}Stay signed-in </p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Note the addition of the `{{form.csrf_token}}` line.

You need to provide this for the form to render correctly if you don't use the `wtf.quickform` method.

Comment: I tried adding `{{form.csrf_token}}` but it still won't render.

Comment: I don't think it's my forms -- I think it's my HTML. I've deleted everything in the `login.html` content block and replaced it with basic HTML and it still doesn't render. I think that my content block in `login.html` isn't being displayed by the content block in `layout.html'.